# Is there a way to programatically check airplane mode status on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm creating a simple WP7 app, to have all network settings in one place, and to be able to pin it to the startpage of the phone. I can check the WiFi, and Cellular Data status using the  DeviceNetworkInformation class, and I found, that there is currently no API for bluetooth. The only thing I didn't found answer to is if there is a way to check if airplane mode is turned on or off. For now I'm assuming it can't be done, but it would be great if someone could tell it for sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API to check for Airplane mode that I know of.

You could simply try to use the network and handle exceptions or [query the API for network changes and availability](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-get-Phone-Network-Information-in-WP7-Mango-via-code)

Answer (score 1):

Airplane mode is a setting on your phone that lets you turn off the cellular connection, Wi-Fi, FM radio, and Bluetooth on your phone simultaneously. While you're in Airplane mode, you can still use your FM radio and turn on Wi-Fi and Bluetooth separately. Cellular remains off until you turn Airplane mode off. So it is best to determine if the Network Services you need are enabled or disabled, rather than checking if the phone is is Airplane mode or not, because that may or maynot mean that bluetooth or Wi-Fi is enabled.

Comment: I'm indicating cellular data and wifi separately, I would do the same with bluetooth if there was an api for that. I was just curious if I can or cannot indicate airplane mode too. Apparently not.